# Does Cull the Weak also apply against stunned enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Does [**Cull the Weak**](http://d3db.com/skill/i/cull-the-weak) also apply against stunned enemies?

[image: Cull the Weak: Damage against slowed enemies increased by 15%]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Cull_the_Weak). Cull the Weak does in fact **only** work on slowed enemies. A lot of Traps Demon Hunters use this because of the slowing effects of certain traps such as Caltrops.

Comment: Caltrops has no slowing rune.  The slowing is the base effect of Caltrops; all the other effects like damage or immobilization are from the runes